# How can I prevent an event when detect the form values has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added some js code when html loaded. Like below

```
var form = $('form');
$(':input').change(function() {
    if ($('[name=form-update-detector]', form).length == 0) {
        $(form).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="form-update-detector"/>')
    }
    $('[name=form-update-detector]', form).val('true');
});
```

It works.
My question is when I detect form values have changed, how can I warn users when they click other elements (bound a redirect event) without saving this form?
The elements which bind the event may be `<a></a>`, `<p></p>` or any others. The code may be `onclick="someEvent()"` or `$('#someId').on('click',function(){})` or a href etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the initial values (when the form is loaded) in a variable say cleanData and the when the user clicks the other element on which you have some other action attached, you can first take the form data in another variable say dirtyData, then compare these two and if equal then proceed to the action attached on the element clicked, else show a warning.

Comment: I see, I can detect easily if any changes in form without compare two values by my js code attached above. But I cann't get the event that user clicked and cann't detect is it a redirect event.

Comment: I suppose you must have attached the redirect event on a particular DOM element. Am I right?